# Passing arguments to a method that need to be used for generic<T>?

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am currently working on a IoC container abstraction that sits on top of StructureMap. The idea is that it could work with other IoC containers as well.

```
public interface IRegister
{
    IRegister RegisterType(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, params Argument[] arguments);
}

public abstract class ContainerBase : IRegister
{
    public abstract IRegister RegisterType(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, params Argument[] arguments);
}

public class StructureMapContainer : ContainerBase
{
    public StructureMapContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public IContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public override IRegister RegisterType(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, params Argument[] arguments)
    {
        // StructureMap specific code
        Container.Configure(x =>
        {
            var instance = x.For(serviceType).Use(implementationType);
            arguments.ForEach(a => instance.CtorDependency<string>(a.Name).Is(a.Value));
        });

        return this;
    }
}

public class Argument
{       
    public Argument(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
}
```

I can execute this code by doing the following:

```
//IContainer is a StructureMap type
IContainer container = new Container(); 
StructureMapContainer sm = new StructureMapContainer(container);

sm.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository), typeof(Repository));
```

The problem arises when I try to pass in constructor arguments. StructureMap allows you to fluently chain however many CtorDependency calls as you want but requires the constructor parameter name, value and type. So I could do something like this:

```
sm.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository), typeof(Repository), new Argument("connectionString", "myConnection"), new Argument("timeOut", "360"));
```

This code works as CtorDependency is currently of type string and both arguments are strings as well.

```
instance.CtorDependency<string>(a.Name).Is(a.Value)
```

How can I pass in multiple constructor arguments BUT of any type to this method? Is it possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a question: Why aren't you using something like `RegisterType<TService, TImplementation>(...)`?

Comment: I do, I have extensions methods that have that signature but I decided to only include the necessary code to illustrate the problem at hand.

Comment: Ah, right. Regarding your question: I think you won't get around using reflection here, but it should be appropiate to use it here.

Comment: Could you give me an example so I can narrow down my search. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4101821/127059 this might be a good starting point. Dynamic invocation of generic methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dynamic, anonymous object to pass in your arguments.  Then use reflection to inspect the properties.  The values can be any type.

```
dynamic example = new
{
    a = 3,
    b = "hello"
};

foreach (PropertyInfo p in example.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    string key = p.Name;
    dynamic value = p.GetValue(example, null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, value);
}
```

This outputs

> a: 3
>   b: hello

Just modify as necessary for your needs.

**Edit:**

Just so this is clear.  Your registration method would take a dynamic parameter.  It would be *something* like this.  I don't have StructureMap, but this should get you in the right direction.

```
public override IRegister RegisterType(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, dynamic arguments)
{
    // StructureMap specific code
    Container.Configure(x =>
    {
        var instance = x.For(serviceType).Use(implementationType);
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in arguments.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            string key = p.Name;
            object value = p.GetValue(arguments, null);
            instance.CtorDependency<string>(key).Is(value));
        }
     });

    return this;
}
```

**Edit Part Deux:**

Okay, so you're wanting to be able to pass in any data type for the key.  Is this closer to what you're needing?  You get the method by name, the turn it into a closed generic by calling `MakeGenericMethod`.  Then you invoke it.

```
var method = instance
    .GetType()
    .GetMethod("CtorDependency")
    .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { key.GetType() });
method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { key });
```

Comment: Amy, I think I did a poor job emphasizing where the core problem is. It is on this line: instance.CtorDependency<T>(key).Is(value)) where T currently is string. This code is inside the foreach loop. The questions becomes what happens if the first argument is an int, the second a bool, and then a string... how do I translate that into instance.CtorDependency<int>(key).Is(value)) then instance.CtorDependency<bool>(key).Is(value)) and finally instance.CtorDependency<string>(key).Is(value))?

Comment: Amy, I think you got it. I haven't tried the code yet but it sure looks like the right direction. Thank you!