# Set an initializer dynamically that expect a Type as input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want set an initializer dynamically that expect a Type as input, but gets an error that says "could not find type or namespeace dbContextType"

```
var dbContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<DbContext>();

var dbContextType = dbContext.GetType();
Database.SetInitializer<dbContextType>(null);
```

Is it posible to set a type like this as input without explicit writing the class name?

Comment: I dont know how that would help

Comment: It would help because it is exactly what you are trying to do, use a runtime type to execute a generic method.

Comment: Also answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101784/calling-a-generic-method-with-a-dynamic-type

Comment: Could you please show me how i can use that with my code?