# Query Entity Framework for list of dynamic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

When querying entity framework for all objects of a given type, you'd do something like this:

```
List<MyDesiredObjects> = _myContext.MyDesiredObjects.ToList();
```

But is there a way one can create a function to query EF to find all objects of a given type if the type is variable? I've created this function, which at least compiles:

```
private List<TEntity> GetFromEF<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    MyDBEntities context = new UnityDBEntities(_entityConnection);

    IObjectContextAdapter adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;
    System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext oContext = adapter.ObjectContext;

    return oContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

But I'm struggling to see how I can call it, never mind actually extract data from it. Using reflection, like this (ucm.MappingType is a Type):

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(BaseXmlReader).GetMethod("GetFromEF");
MethodInfo gMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(  ucm.MappingType.GetType() );
var meh = gMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

Fails with object reference not set to instance of object. And I've not even got to paging my list yet.

Any other way to approach this problem?

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? Is it when you are invoking the method or in GetFromEF?

Comment: It's on method.MakeGenericMethod - but I just spotted that's because method is null.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check that method is not null?

Comment: You're right - it's returning null ( see edit above )

Comment: Also, `GetType()` is used for an object. If `ucm.MappingType` is itself a `Type` (not an object), then use `typeof(ucm.MappingType)` instead of `ucm.MappingType.GetType()`

Comment: One way to call a generic method is like this: `var list = GetFromEF<MyDesiredObjects>();` No need to get into reflection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You will probably need to provide these binding flags to GetMethod to enable it to get your private method BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance

Comment: @colin Attempting either of these things causes a compile error "type or namespace ucm cannot be found". You can't seem to pass a variable to call a generic i.e. GetFromEF<somethingDynamic> .. GetFromEF<String> is fine.

Comment: @mayabelle See above - same problem

Comment: @MikeNorgate OK, thanks! That's got me down to the invoke, which "requires a target"

Comment: The first parameter of the invoke needs to be an instance of BaseXmlReader, you cannot invoke on a null instance

Comment: Apologies. I hadn't understood the problem was how to call a generic method with a dynamic type http://stackoverflow.com/q/4101784/150342

Comment: @MikeNorgate That's it, thanks. Feel free to post as an answer if you want but someone else nailed it around the same time. Whose do I accept?

Comment: Accept the current answer. Just mark my comments as useful if they helped

Comment: @Mike - Sorry, didn't mean to take your answer. I stopped reading the comments and was typing up my answer, I guess we posted around the same time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your issue of having a null `MethodInfo method`:

`GetMethod` will only search for public members.  You can change your method to public, or include nonpublic methods like this:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(BaseXmlReader)
                       .GetMethod("GetFromEF", 
                                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Also, I'm assuming that your GetFromEF method is on a class called BaseXmlReader? If not, that needs to be replaced with the class name.

Then you can invoke like this:

```
BaseXmlReader instance = new BaseXmlReader();
MethodInfo method = typeof(BaseXmlReader)
                       .GetMethod("GetFromEF", 
                                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo gMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ucm.MappingType));
var result = gMethod.Invoke(instance, null);
```

or like this if being called from inside itself:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(BaseXmlReader)
                       .GetMethod("GetFromEF", 
                                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo gMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ucm.MappingType));
var result = gMethod.Invoke(this, null);
```

Comment: It's actually being called from inside itself, so the Invoke is gMethod.Invoke(this, null) ... but the principal is the same. Thanks!