# Use class as variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have a class called InstalledObjects, and all objects like walls, door etc will inherit from this one. Now, I would like to instantiate a GameObject in a method, and ask in the method for a InstalledObject, that could be a Wall or a Door since they both inherit from InstalledObject.

My problem is that I can store in a variable a script.

First, this method is called

```
public void CreateBasicWall()
{
     buildHandler.installedObject = new Wall();
}
```

That its stored here:

```
public InstalledObject installedObject;
```

And finally gets called here

```
BuildTile(t, buildModeTile);
```

And does that:

```
void Build(Tile tile, InstalledObject installedObject)
{
    if(installedObject == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No se va a construir nada");
        return;
    }
    GameObject go = new GameObject();
    go.AddComponent<installedObject>();

}
```

Ignore the tile. It wont let me add the installedObject since is a var and not a type.

I remember that the class Wall inherits from InstalledObject, and I would like to have it as var so I can reuse code, but any other solution is appreciated.

Comment: You can't pass in a variable for generics. (`AddComponent<T>`). See [Calling a generic method with a dynamic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101784/calling-a-generic-method-with-a-dynamic-type)

Comment: And this is called inside a void? Never used types before

Comment: The return type doesn't matter .. counts for void or anything else

Comment: Assuming that `InstalledObject` is of type `MonoBehaviour` since you are trying to use it for `AddComponent` your code is invalid anyway! You can't use `new Wall()` for a class of type `MonoBehaviour` .. it can only be created using `AddComponent<ClassName>()` or alternatively the overload taking a type `AddComponent(typeof(ClassName))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said already using dynamic variables for a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics) method (`AddComponent<T>`) is not possible directly only maybe using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232535/7111561) but I wouldn't recommend it .. especially not if you are new to c#.

---

Assuming that `InstalledObject` is of type `MonoBehaviour` since you are trying to use it for `AddComponent` your code is invalid anyway!

You can't use `new Wall()` for a class of type `MonoBehaviour` .. it can only be created using `AddComponent<ClassName>()` or alternatively the overload taking a type [`AddComponent(typeof(ClassName))`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)

So what you can do instead is not storing an "instance" (as said you can't use `new` anyway) you could rather only store the according type

```
public Type typeToInstall;
```

and then pass it on like

```
public void CreateBasicWall()
{
     buildHandler.typeToInstall = typeof(Wall);
}

void Build(Tile tile, Type typeToInstall)
{
    if(typeToInstall == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No se va a construir nada");
        return;
    }

    GameObject go = new GameObject().AddComponent(typeToInstall);

    // or even a bit shorter
    //new GameObject("New GameObject", typeToInstall);
}
```

You can also make this method a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics) itself and [constraint passed the type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) to `Component` (the mother class of anything you can attach to a `GameObject`) just to be sure. Passing in any other type will then already throw a compiler error. Then you can also use `AddComponent<T>` again

```
void Build<T>(Tile tile, T typeToInstall) where T : Component // or maybe even InstalledObject ;)
{
    if(typeToInstall == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No se va a construir nada");
        return;
    }

    new GameObject().AddComponent<T>();

    // or still use
    //new GameObject("New GameObject", typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, however if you want to keep your current architecture, you need virtual or abstract functions.

Each class knows its own type, however the functions you call on it depend on the type of the variable holding the class, unless it's an abstract or virtual function.

I'd suggest reading up on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual).

Here's one way to do it:

```
void Build(Tile tile, InstalledObject installedObject)
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(installedObject,
        "No se va a construir nada");

    GameObject go = new GameObject();
    installedObject.AddSelfToGameObject(go);
}
```

and in your Build.cs

```
public abstract class Build
{
    [...]
    public abstract void AddSelfToGameObject(GameObject go);
}

public class Building:Build
{
    [...]
    public override void AddSelfToGameObject(GameObject go)
    {
        go.AddComponent<BuildingScript>();
    }
}
```

The `abstract` on the `Build` class is only necessary if you never create a `Build` class alone, only a child class of `Build`. You can remove the `abstract` on the class and replace it on the function by `virtual`.